# How to iterate through map when pass a class to map

Tags: c++

I am writing a simple code that. I've created two objects from class Employee that have two method. getData() and displayData(), and I've made a map of Employee type. It is taking input but to iterate through map by calling the displayData() that is in class.

Here is the code. Ive got the error that error: 'struct std::pair<const int, Employee>' has no member named 'displayData'

Any suggestions or am i doing it wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;
class Employee {
    private:
       int id; 
       string name;
    public :
       void getData(){
          cin >> id >> name;
       }
    
       void displayData(){
          cout << id <<" "<<name<<endl;
       }
  };

int main() {

    map<int, Employee> m1;
    map<int, Employee> :: iterator it;
    Employee e1,e2;

    //for (i)
    e1.getData();
    m1[1] = e1;
    e2.getData();
    m1[2] = e2;

    for (it = m1.begin(); it!=m1.end(); ++it){
       cout << (*it).first.displayData() << (*it).second.displayData() <<endl;
    }

    return 0;

 }
```

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: Please clarify your question what you want to achieve. However your current code is syntactically not correct. (*it).first represent here the key of map which is 'int' datatype and (*it).second represent the Employee. So for int data type there is no method displayData.

To just iterate and displayData, you just need to write "(*it).second.displayData()" inside for loop.

Comment: If you find yourself iterating through a map, you have chosen a wrong container.

Comment: @n.m. Not always. On rare occasions, we want to use a map for fast insertion, but then we iterate over it to extract the results. But usually it's a red flag, yes

Answer (score 2):

> Here is the code. Ive got the error that error: 'struct
> std::pair<const int, Employee>' has no member named 'displayData'

The compiler tells you exactly what is wrong, you may have a Misconception about std::maps, std::maps holds a key-value pair([More details About Maps](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map)) which is a `std::pair` which can be accessed via an `iterator` or the value accessed directly via `map[key]`. `iterator::first` holds the key which in your code is an `int`, while `iterator::second` holds the value which in your case right now is an object called `Employee`, hence `(*it).first.displayData()` error.

This line is also incorrect, and would produce compiler errors.

```
cout << (*it).first.displayData() << (*it).second.displayData() <<endl;
```

`(*it).second.displayData`() will return the return type of the function since this is a function call, in this case a type of **void**. You can simply call the function like this to achieve your desired result in every iteration.

```
std::cout << it->first << " ";
it->second.displayData();
```

*Always trust compiler errors.*

Answer (score 0):

In C++ 17, you can use structured bindings for more readbility:

```
for (auto [eid, employee] : m1)
{
    std::cout << eid << ": ";
    employee.displayData();
}
```